# looping through views in android

Tags: android

I am iterating through views that i have dynamically created

```
int childCnt=dynAddrId.getChildCount();

for(int i=0;i<childCnt;i++){
    Spinner ref=(Spinner) dynAddrId.findViewWithTag(i).findViewWithTag("spinnerTag");
    ref.getSelectedItem().toString();       
}
```

`ref.getSelectedItem().toString()` has value `{id=1, proof=driving licence}`

Note: `sincedynamic` content is involved in next loop for **proof** i may get `PAN CARD`

How can I get the value  `driving licence` and store it in a string

---

### EDIT

CODE USED TO POPULATE SPINNER

```
/* Create a Spinner .*/
        spinnerView=new Spinner(getActivity());
        spinnerView.setTag("spinnerTag");
        spinnerView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f));
        AdptAddressProof adapter=new AdptAddressProof(addressProofSpinnerData, getActivity());
        spinnerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //SET THE SPINNER ID FOR DYNAMICALLY CREATED OBJECT
```

---

```
public class AdptAddressProof extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> categorySpinnerData;
    Context context;
    //ArrayList<ListObject> objects;

    public AdptAddressProof(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> _categorySpinnerData, Context _context) {
        super();
        context=_context;
        categorySpinnerData=_categorySpinnerData;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return categorySpinnerData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return categorySpinnerData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        HashMap<String, String> mapData=categorySpinnerData.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adpt_categories_spinner, null);
        }

        TextView txtCategoryNameId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCategoryNameId);

        txtCategoryNameId.setText(mapData.get("proof"));
        txtCategoryNameId.setTag(mapData.get("id"));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Blackbelt ...ya ... but in the debugger i am seeing this value ...android is showing that value !

Comment: @Blackbelt It's not a JSONObject exactly. JSONObject's use `:` instead of `=`.

Comment: Without calling the `toString` method, can you not access the properties of that, by considering it to be a simple `object`?

Comment: @Blackbelt ..Also note i had set the id for that object as `1`  ...next `2` and so on  value is driving licence

Comment: @D4nC00per ...... all i am trying to do is the value of spinner but in this way by iterating the views !

Comment: How do you populate the spinner ?

Comment: `Object item = ref.getSelectedItem(); String proof = item.proof;`

Comment: I see, then getSelectedItem is returning you an HashMap! `HashMap<String, String> item = (HashMap<String, String>) ref.getSelectedItem(); String value = item.get("proof");`

Comment: @D4nC00per ... but i cannot resolve that `proof` to a variable ...since its not declared nor the property

Comment: @Blackbelt ...post it as answer so i can accept it ! ... Your solution works !

Comment: @Devrath what do you use to write your code? You should have been able to hover over the `getSelectedItem` method to see what it returns, in a good IDE such as Android Studio or Eclipse. Even looking up the documentation for that method would have shown what it returns. I hope that helps in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your case `getSelectedItem` returns an `HashMap<String, String>`. To retrieve the content of proof you can simply do:

```
HashMap<String, String> item = (HashMap<String, String>) ref.getSelectedItem(); 
String value = item.get("proof");
```